Excel Count if first character is 0 in string
I am looking for an Excel function that will check down a column and look for cells where the first character is a 0.
In the case of the below example, you can see that there are a total of 3 cells in the below column that have a 0 as the first character. I want to simply get a count of these for the column. I thought of using a COUNTIF formula but I wasn't sure how to make sure it's only checking the first character, as there could be a possibility of 0's in other places (i.e. 10/10, 5/100, etc..)


A single function? I would look at left() to get the first character, if() to test for 0 and sum() if true... This is a hint to let you expand your skills.

Something like IF(LEFT(B1; 1)=1

@RobertKock thanks however that is only checking cell B1 in your formula, I want it to check all the cells in a column.

You could try using one of the following, assume you are using MS365:


• Using TEXTBEFORE() function:
=SUM(N(IFNA(--TEXTBEFORE(B2:B21,"/")=0,0)))


• Or, Using COUNTIF() or COUNTIFS() with wild card operator :
=COUNTIF(B:B,"0/*")


If you are insisting for a dynamic approach something like this you could try as well:


=COUNTIF(B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(2,1/(B:B<>""))),"0/*")



Thanks for the two formulas! I was able to use the first formula with the TEXTBEFORE function; I'm curious what the two dashes (--) do in the formula?  I could not get the 2nd formula to work for me, it showed a Circular reference error and then just show 0 as the result.

Hi @Nick , -- means double unary, is an operation used to coerce TRUE FALSE values to ones and zeros in more advanced formulas, especially formulas that work with arrays! Also, the second one should be working possibly you have added the formula in the same range or cells where the data lays.

Yes the 2nd formula does work if I put the formula over to the side (in another column), but not if I have it at the bottom of the same column with the other values.

@Nick if you put the function in the same column it is counting, it tries to count itself - how do you think that will work?

I understand, but ideally I would like the cell range it's referencing to be dynamic, in cases where I need to add an additional record inside the existing range, so I'd rather use something like B:B.

@Nick so put it in the first row and start from row 2.

@Nick see my update, sorry I wasn't in front of the computer. Here you can use this as well: =COUNTIF(B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(2,1/(B:B<>""))),"0/*") this will be dynamic

As already mentioned by Mayukh, you can use CountIf() combined with regular expressions, although the usage might be dangerous as you are looking for "numbers", containing a zero.
A typical example of CountIf() with regular expressions can be found in the following screenshot:


Just wanted to let you know that these are called wildcards, something different to regular expressions.

@JvdV: I was already wondering about the complete list of those characters: * means "any number of whatever characters", according to the online help there is ?, meaning "exactly one instance of whatever character". Are there more?

Those are it. You could also use a ~ (tilde) to escape a wildcard and make it a literal.

And here is another version:
SUM(IF(LEFT(A1:A12,1)*1=0,1,0))
But you seem to have already accepted the other answer.

And showing it in the same column as I suggested in the comments:


Results in a #VALUE! message for me

@Nick then you need to check as it works in two versions for me. Did you edit the column reference? mine is to column A... Or you might need to do ctrl+shift+enter.
